Can't see any object added in render view using Fspy
I have added an object into the scene using the Fspy camera but when I switch to render view I can't see any object but only the image of the Fspy camera.
Also when I try to render an image just to check, everything is transparent.
Can someone please help me out?

Ask the author(s) of Fspy or on a forum that supports it? - Please don't ask questions in all-bold text in future!

It would be helpful to see your scene. Can you share the blend file? There can be many reasons why you do not see the objects. Camera clipping, objects are disabled for rendering, transparent shader, holdout option is enabled, messed up compositor settings, ...
